# During installation of rake db:create in ubuntu 12 the following error is showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

During installation of rake db:create in ubuntu 12 the following error is showing

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `task' for #<Spec::Rake::SpecTask:0xb6fa4c0c>
/home/sys03/fedena/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:28:in `initialize'
/home/sys03/fedena/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:58:in `new'
/home/sys03/fedena/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:58
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9
/home/sys03/fedena/Rakefile:10
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

please guide me how to solve the error

Comment: try upgrading rake: 'bundle update rake' and rerun

Comment: try this>> rake db:create RAILS_ENV='development'

Comment: which version of Rake you are using??

Comment: rake versions 10.3.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7

Comment: I wonder which ubuntu you're talking about: 12.04 (LTS one) or 12.10

Comment: ya i have tried above commands but still error is showing

Comment: or please send me proper installation document for Ubuntu 12 Operating System Please